# Can another MS Access DBS be used like a Namespace?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to use the class objects in a separate MS Access database without importing the class module and all its dependencies?

I have a database project that is fully running and I would like to use some of its' custom classes and data in a separate project. I would rather not have to import the class modules and their dependent queries as well as to link to their dependent tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
(This must be at least 30 chars, so here they are)